# How to detect CRM current user name from inspecting page DOM / HTML?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynatrace

I am trying to configure Dynatrace user sessions detection to detect real user name of logged in users into our MS Dynamics CRM v. 8 on-prem installed application, this process is called User Tagging in DT,

I need to know in which part of the page DOM / HTML the current user name string is persisted, for instance at the top right of the CRM page I do see my small icon photo and if i click i do see my name in the pop-up menu,

has anybody handled CRM user tagging with DT before and knows how to grab user name?

Thanks,
Davide

Comment: never mind, i found it, it is inside an "a" element with id=navTabButtonUserInfoUserNameId

Comment: it actually started working when using this full selector in Dynatrace, since unles the user opens the menu, the above item is not loaded... #navBarUserInfoTextId > span.navTabButtonUserInfoText.navTabButtonUserInfoWorker

Comment: yes, basically it would be mapped to the DOM element...we have used cookie value..